# Force fake response using ActiveMerchant response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

have a transaction model similar to [RailsCasts ActiveMerchant tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant).

How can I create a fake response?

Tried something like the following but no luck.

```
response = @success=true, @params = {"ref" => "123"}, @authorization = "54321", ...
```

models/order_transaction.rb

```
class OrderTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  serialize :params

  def response=(response)
    self.success       = response.success?
    self.authorization = response.authorization
    self.message       = response.message
    self.params        = response.params
  rescue ActiveMerchant::ActiveMerchantError => e
    self.success       = false
    self.authorization = nil
    self.message       = e.message
    self.params        = {}
  end
end
```

Comment: YES, YES, YES.  Everything except response.success? is working.  Am using it like above.  response = OpenStruct.new and then passing in response.success = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like

```
a = OpenStruct.new
def a.success?
 true
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  Never new about OpenStruct.

Comment: Note that you can use "success?" as a member name when constructing OpenStruct:

    OpenStruct.new('success?' => true)